# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello  I have the following code

```
train=jsonlite::fromJSON("/home/felipe/Templates/Archivo de prueba/databritanica.json")

map<-get_map(location="united kingdom"  ,zoom=12,source="osm")

p <- ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=train, aes(x=X, y=Y, color=factor(LSOA_name)), alpha=0.05) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1.0, size=6.0),
                               title="Type of Crime")) +
  scale_colour_brewer(type="qual",palette="Paired") + 
  ggtitle("Top Crimes in Britain") +
  theme_light(base_size=20) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
ggsave("united kingdom_top_crimes_map.png", p, width=14, height=10, units="in")
```

The main goal of the script is to take the data from the JSON file and mapping over the map I obtain with get_map.

Executing this code give me this error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found

The data contain in the JSON file have the following format:

```
[
    {"Month":"2014-05",
     "Longitude":-2.747770,
     "Latitude":53.389499,
     "Location":"On or near Cronton Road",
     "LSOA_name":"Halton 001B",
     "Crime_type":"Other theft"},

    {"Month":"2014-05",
     "Longitude":-2.799099,
     "Latitude":53.354676,
     "Location":"On or near Old Higher Road",
     "LSOA_name":"Halton 008B",
     "Crime_type":"Anti-social behaviour"},

    Thousands of lines more

]
```

What I am missing here?  what can be the problem?

UPDATE

this is the output after applying str(train) like the user pascal said:

```
str(train)
'data.frame':   10632 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Month     : chr  "2014-05" "2014-05" "2014-05" "2014-05" ...
 $ Longitude : num  -2.75 -2.8 -2.8 -2.87 -2.87 ...
 $ Latitude  : num  53.4 53.4 53.4 53.5 53.5 ...
 $ Location  : chr  "On or near Cronton Road" "On or near Old Higher Road" "On or near Higher Road" "On or near Sanderling Road" ...
 $ LSOA_name : chr  "Halton 001B" "Halton 008B" "Halton 008B" "Knowsley 001A" ...
 $ Crime_type: chr  "Other theft" "Anti-social behaviour" "Anti-social behaviour" "Anti-social behaviour" ...
```

Now, this is another output  after applying dput(head(train)) like the user 42 said

```
> dput(head(train))
structure(
   list(
    Month = c("2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", "2014-05", 
              "2014-05", "2014-05"),
    Longitude = c(-2.74777, -2.799099, -2.804451, 
                 -2.873557, -2.871609, -2.871841),
    Latitude = c(53.389499, 53.354676, 
                 53.352456, 53.485957, 53.489432, 53.489745),
    Location = c("On or near Cronton Road", 
                 "On or near Old Higher Road", "On or near Higher Road",               "On or near Sanderling Road", 
                 "On or near Watts Close", "On or near Gilescroft Avenue"), 
    LSOA_name = c("Halton 001B", 
                  "Halton 008B", "Halton 008B", "Knowsley 001A",                "Knowsley 001A", 
                   "Knowsley 001A"), 
   Crime_type = c("Other theft", "Anti-social behaviour", 
                  "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour",
                  "Anti-social behaviour", 
                  "Anti-social behaviour")), 
   .Names = c("Month", "Longitude", "Latitude", 
              "Location", "LSOA_name", "Crime_type"),
    row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here the outputs of of the variable "train"

Comment: Please add the output of `str(train)`

Comment: Is the JSON output you offer the exact contents of the top of the file? (I hate seeing `...` in data examples.) Are all the items in the same order w.r.t. to the attribute names? It implies that we should be able to read your mind about all the possible variations.) Why not post output from `dput(head(train))`?

Comment: @Pascal    I update the post with the outputs of "train",    thank you

Comment: @42-  I update the post with the outputs of "train" with the function dput(head(train)),  thank you

Comment: There is no `X` in `train`. Did you mean `Longitude` and `Latitude` rather than `X` and `Y`?